# Edit expression in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, zk

```
($F{pa1} == 1 ? "A" : ($F{pa1} == 2 ? "P" : ($F{pa1} == 3 ? "WO" : ($F{pa1} == 4 ? "WOP" : "½P"))))
```

How to convert an `Integer` to `String` and assign the value to Status?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use .intValue(). If you go to the expression builder (i don't have jasper in front of me, i forget what it's called), you can just select the field you want to use, then it will show which java methods you can apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

did you try just $F{SOME_FIELD}.toString()?

Thanks,
Arty